# Connection to db@localhost failed in IntelliJ

Tags: database, intellij-idea, derby

I'm trying to create a database in Intellij using Apache Derby. I have everything configured, but when I try to create the database, an error message appears:

```
Connection to ejercicio@localhost failed.
[08001][40000] java.net.ConnectException: Error on connecting to localhost server in port 1.527 with the message Connection refused: connect.
```

I have tried everything (executing startNetworkServer, writing create=true at database title) and it still doesn't connect. 
Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: After you start the network server, does 'netstat' confirm that it's up and running? Can you connect from the command line using 'ij'? What operating system are you on?

Comment: @BryanPendleton I'm using Windows 10, and IntelliJ 2017. I don't know what 'netstat' is, sorry.

Comment: Well, it sounds like your network server failed to start. I'd suggest looking more closely at the `startNetworkServer` part of your steps. Include the full output of the terminal window where you ran `startNetworkServer`, for example, and also include the `derby.log` from the directory which the Network Server is using as its Derby home directory. Also, check your Windows Firewall to see if it is allowing connections to port 1527; I'm not sure if that affects localhost-only connections or not. And learn about `netstat`, it's a good tool to know.